# 'which is' or 'one is'

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I have sentence.

> Algorithm is classified as a probabilistic algorithms, which is used
>   for solving [name of problem] problems.

Can I say: "*Algorithm is classified as a probabilistic algorithms. One is used for
solving [name of problem] problem*" ?

Answer (score 1):

Strunk and White, *The Elements of Style*, 3rd Edition

"`That` is the defining or restrictive pronoun, `which` the non-defining pronoun." - Page 59

`That` would refer to the specific algorithm mentioned before, `which` would add information.

That to me seems to indicate that `which` is the pronoun you're looking for rather than `one` which is more nebulous.

Comment: Sorry, typo, "Strunk" should be in there.

Comment: And now it is "Strunk".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are referring to a single algorithm or a set of algorithms. On the basis of your above statement it appears to me that you are defining a specific algorithm. 
The sentence could be framed as:

> A probabilistic algorithm is used for solving [name of problem] problems.

OR

> An algorithm is probabilistic in nature, if it is used for solving [name of problem] problems.

Hope this helps.